# Unity mobile UI only works in game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a mobile game in Unity and while making my UI it all worked fine in unitys game view but when I built the game none of my text or buttons showed up only a few images I had as a background for the UI. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: i bet your screen resolution and the mobiles are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by clicking add open scenes button.